# Loading scripts from HTML string wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, wkwebview

Is it possible to load script files from Xcode project via html loaded with WKWebView loadHTMLString method?

For example if I have a project named DemoProject, with javascript files called script1.js and script2.js in the root directory. Then I'm loading an html string that tries to reference those files. Is that possible? If so how do I properly reference those files?

Comment: Try this <script src="script1.js"></script>  <script src="script2.js"></script>

Comment: I did, it's not being found.

Comment: Are HTML file and Scripts both in the same Target?

Comment: There's no html file, I load a string, which contains html, into the wkwebview. That string contains <script src="script1.js"></script> <script src="script2.js"></script>. Those files are located in the project's root directory.

Comment: What about convert files content to string and then inject with webView.stringByEvaluatingJavascript? i dont remember the exact name of the function but you can check it out. Hope it helps

Comment: @ImmortalBajan, Were you able to load js files? Could you please provide us the technic?

Comment: No, I had to load in javascript which lived on a site instead of loading javascript files from within the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting it as user script.
If your folder structure is like this, use the below function to load it as user script

[image]

```
private func fetchScript() -> WKUserScript!{

    var jsScript = ""
    if let jsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hello", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "scripts"){
        do
        {
            jsScript = try String(contentsOfFile: jsPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }catch{

            print("Error")
        }
    }

    let wkAlertScript = WKUserScript(source: jsScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    return wkAlertScript
}
```

Add it to controller

```
func registerScriptsAndEvents() {

    let controller = self.wkWebView.configuration.userContentController
    // Load the entire script to the document
    controller.addUserScript(fetchScript())
}
```

Comment: You can check this project https://github.com/anoop4real/WKWebViewExperiments i tried a lot of things

Comment: @anoop4real, the hello.js file should be called through start.html file.